# Need an easy way to allow users to change a recursive database schema without needing to modify tables in SQL Server or Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I've got an ASP.NET project, and the customer would like a way to easily change the recursive parent-child relationships between certain items in a table. For example, if Entity2 is a child of Entity1, and the user wants Entity1 to now be a child of Entity3, I need a way to allow them to do this without needing to open up SQL Server or Visual Studio. This is not something that needs to be modified very often; maybe a few times a year, so the solution doesn't need to be super-fancy, just elegant. The only solution that I can think of is maybe allow the user to modify the structure from an XML file and and recreate or modify the SQL tables using SQLXMLBulkload. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is that you re-design your database.  Your example describes a scenario where updating records seems like the most appropriate action.  If you need to re-design your database for that reason, you have a bad design.

Comment: The problem is that the customer doesn't want to edit tables in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a separate mapping table that will have two columns parent id and child id. You can give your client an interface say with two drop downs (one to select parent and other to select client) and a save button (that will simply save this mapping.).

Hope this helps.